# Как правильно вывести html через функцию echo

Tags: php, wordpress

В теге `use` идёт ссылка на `svg` спрайт и эта ссылка "не работает", то есть не задаёт правильный адрес.

```
<?php

    $value = get_field( "цитата" );

    if( $value ) {

        echo "
        <div class=\"about-block__text\">
        <h2>$value</h2>
            <div class=\"social\">
                <a class=\"svg\" href=\"\">
                   <svg>
                       <use xlink:href=\"<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/sprite-inline.svg#icon_fb\"></use>  // и данная ссылка просто не выполняется 
                   </svg></a>
                <a class=\"svg\" href=\"\">
                   <svg>
            </div>
        </div>";

    } else {

        echo "<div class=\"about-block__text\" style=\" display: none\"></div>";

    }
?>
```

Как записать этот код правильно?

Comment: Задай вопрос так, чтобы его можно было понять.

Comment: Учите что такое конкатенация в php.
Ваша проблема в том, что у Вас "вывод в выводе" `echo`.
Вам нужно заменить часть кода `<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>` банально на `".get_template_directory_uri()."`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php 
    $value = get_field('цитата');
    if ($value): ?> 
        <div class="about-block__text">
            <h2><?= $value ?></h2>
            <div class="social">
                <a class="svg" href="">
                    <svg>
                        <use xlink:href="<?= get_template_directory_uri() ?>/img/sprite-inline.svg#icon_fb"></use>
                    </svg>
                </a>
                <a class="svg" href="">
                   <svg>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php else: ?>
       <div class="about-block__text" style="display: none"></div>
<?php endif ?>
```

Язык PHP дает возможность использования вот такого синтаксиса. Надеюсь, Вам это значительно упростит жизнь :)

Ваши html тэги я не правил, возможно стоит что-то изменить.